# Dojo JsonRestStore, fetch, onError callback and HTTP status code?

Tags: dojo

I would like to know how to obtain the HTTP status code returned after a fetch() operation is performed. I have specified the onComplete and onError callbacks to the fetch() call. 
The onError is called in case of an error, but I am unable to obtain the HTTP status code from the parameter passed to onError (it's  just the request, not the response).

With XhrGet I was able to get the status code from the ioArgs, and it seems that the JsonRestStore does not handle it that way.

I'm using Dojo 1.5.1 (and I really cannot upgrade yet to 1.6)

Answer (score 0):

The error handler is given two arguments. The second argument (which I called config) has a property called xhr which contains... status and status text.

```
dojo.xhrGet({
    url:'/bogusPath/',
    error:function(error, config){
        console.log('XHR-ErrorHandle',arguments);
        console.log('XHR-ErrorHandle-status:',config.xhr.status);
        console.log('XHR-ErrorHandle-statusText:',config.xhr.statusText);
    }
})
```

Returns:

XHR-ErrorHandle [Error, Object]

XHR-ErrorHandle-status: **404**

XHR-ErrorHandle-statusText: **Not Found**